# Functionally combine arrays with other arrays or singles

Tags: c#, arrays

I want to return a new int[] by passing both int[] and int to a function.

Was thinking I could do something like

```
static public int[] BuildAddress(params object[] addresses)
{
    foreach(object o in addresses)
    {
        if(typeof(o) == int)
        {

        }
        if(typeof(o) == int[])
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Using 'object' isn't going to work, so I just have that there to get the idea across. When I call the function, I want to be able to include both int[] and int variables, as well as just plain numbers typed in.
Is there a way to do generic types in this manner?
At the moment I have it working with just int[] but to call it I have to build it with 'new int[]{3}' when I want to just type '3'.

Comment: will it be at most one `int[]` and few `int` after it, or it can be any combination?

Comment: There is an option to have infinite Parameters, with a stil lfully defined type: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229008.aspx

Comment: It would be an arbitrary combination of both.

Comment: I was thinking of posting an answer, but this seems like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Are you familiar with generic collections like `List<int>` ?

Comment: @Slai: It does sound like he "picked the wrong way" and ran with it way too long.

Comment: Not too clear what you want here. Do you knopw about `void Foo(params int[] args)` ? Why do you use `object` at all, whn you always have `int` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could potentially be a good candidate for a "fluent" style interface. Especially if you are going to doing other things than just collecting integers in an array. Here's how a client would use it:

```
var address = new AddressBuilder()
    .Add(new [] {1,2,3})
    .Add(4)
    .Add(5, 6)
    .Add(new [] {7,8,9})
    //and so forth
    .Build();
```

Here's how you could implement it:

```
public class AddressBuilder
{
    private readonly List<int> _items = new List<int>();

    public AddressBuilder Add(params int[] items)
    {
        _items.AddRange(items);
        return this;
    }

    public int[] Build()
    {
        //whatever you need to do here
        return _items.ToArray();
    }
}
```

You can also overload the Add method to also take say `IEnumerable<int>` so consumers could also pass in collection of ints, or whatever else.

Comment: I'm a little perplexed. What reason would there be for this class to exist when `List<T>` already exists, and you can already add items to it or add an array of items to it? You don't have to call `Build()` on it because, well, it's already built. If I saw this class in my codebase I'd probably just remove it and replace it with a list. If you really need a `params` type overload you could write an extension: `static void AddItems<T>(this List<T> list, params T[] items){ list.AddRange(items); }`

Comment: I’m assuming OP actually needs to do something besides just combine ints (why I said “potentially”). Also List<T> doesn’t return itself, so you don’t get the functional style method chaining you can do with this style interface. Are you familiar with fluent interfaces and why they are useful? This class is just a start, and if there was nothing else added to it, I might agree with you.

Comment: We might gain a second by not typing `list.Add(1); list.AddRange(ints);` But the second someone sees this, they're going to assume that this is doing something more than adding to a list (otherwise it would be a list) and they'll have to look at it to make sure they're using it right. Then they'll see it's just a list and say hmmm... and go back to work having a lost a minute and wondering why there's a class that wraps a list without providing any extra functionality. I just can't see replacing one of the most familiar classes in the framework with a different one that does nothing new.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this using LINQ, you can decide which overloads you need:

```
// for parameters of type int[]
public static int[] BuildAddress(params int[][] addresses)
{
     return addresses.SelectMany(x => x).ToArray();
}

// for parameters of type int with a base int[]
public static int[] BuildAddress(int[] baseAddress, params int[] addresses)
{
     return baseAddress.Concat(addresses).ToArray();
}
```

It's easier to keep different methods for different parameter types (`int` vs `int[]`)

Comment: Is there a way to link functions in a single line?  So maybe I can overload the method, and then do new int[] = buildAddress(base).buildAddress(3).buildAddress(someotherarray) etc where the output of each function is fed into the chain?

Comment: @cmgsup You could change the second function to `this int[] baseAddress` and use it as an extension method

Answer (score 0):

If `BuildAddress` operates on an array of `int[]` or `IEnumerable<int>` then its parameters should be that, and callers should convert their variables to that type before calling the method.

You could declare your method as

```
static public int[] BuildAddress(IEnumerable<int> addresses)
{
    // this is your "real" method
}
```

and have an overload that just calls the first method:

```
static public int[] BuildAddress(params int[] addresses)
{
    // this method just calls the other one.
    return BuildAddress(addresses);
}
```

With a few extra lines of code you've created two ways to call the method.
If they already have an array or list of `int` they can call this one:

```
var myInts = new int[]{1, 2, 3};
var addresses = BuildAddress(myInts);
```

or, if they just have a few `int` variables they can call the second one. But the second one is really just passing the arguments to the first one, so the "real" functionality of the method isn't duplicated.

```
var addresses = BuildAddress(int1, int2, int3);
```

Now, if the caller has something weird like an `int[][]` or `List<int[]>` or `List<int>[]` or "3,4,5", then let the caller flatten or parse or manipulate those values until it has the arguments needed to call `BuildAddress`. Why should `BuildAddress` be responsible for imagining every permutation of possible inputs if it really just takes a set of `int`?

The argument list of a method should be a clear definition of what the caller is sending and what the method is receiving. There is no useful scenario in which either end has to guess. Code that sends the wrong type to a method should generate compiler errors, not runtime errors.

---

If you have a few variables, such an an `int[]` and a few other `ints`, how could you go about constructing a single set of values that you could pass to one of these methods? You could use a `List<int>`, like this:

```
var myListOfInts = new List<int>();
myListOfInts.Add(someInt); // add a single int.
myListOfInts.AddRange(someArrayOrListOfInts); // add a collection of ints.
```

Now the problem of how to pass them all to one method is solved:

```
var output = BuildAddress(myListOfInts);
```

(I'm only pointing this out because there's an answer that proposes *creating a new class* to build a list of values when the framework already includes the perfect class to do just that.)

Comment: I only used object[] as an example, the types are both int[] and int.  How does stringbuilder.append work?  That is probably an approach i need to take, where append is overloaded with both int and int[] but works on the same array to be returned.  How can a method be called again from the same invocation?

Comment: I'll add it to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The simple way would be to expect the Consuming Programmer to just provide a pre-created array of Integers. Indeed for some types it is **unlikely** that the progammer will ever hand you a T, rather then a T[] array of size 1.

That being said, the .NET Framework has support for variable amounts of parameters: [params](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/params).

The exact avalibiltiy varries by your source language, with C# having gotten it around 6 or 5 I think. Basically the compiler will turn a "comma seperated list of paramters" into a Array automagically. I am not sure if it supports mixing T and T[] in teh parameter list. But again, that depends on the sourcecode langauge you use.

However, as Slai pointed out in the comments above if you jsut want to add Elements to a Array, a `list[int]` wiht 99% propabiltiy the droid you are looking for. Being a wrapper around a array taht will grow automagically as you add elements is literally it's purpose in any Language.